# My PC becomes extremely slow step by step with PhpStorm and npm start

Tags: node.js, angular, performance, phpstorm

My problem is that all my own PC's works extremely slowly in an incremental manner with PhpStorm last version and Angular version 7 without knowing the cause.

And there is my steps which I made to search and test about my issue:

1. I changed 3 of my PC's with 3 specifications:

   - the first is a `Dell with i5 processor & 4GO of RAM`
   - the second is a Mac with `Dell with i5 processor & 4GO of RAM` too
   - and the third is an with `ASUS with i7 processor & 8GO of RAM & Nvidia GTS 1050`

   and I think these specifications are not bad to work with PhpStorm & Angular.
2. In the first and the third PC's I tried to work with Ubuntu then
   with Windows, and i still getting the same extreme slowness issue.
3. In PhpStorm, I activated the **Power Save mode** but no thing was fixed.
4. Finally, in Ubuntu I performed an upgrade & update of node.js & npm, because I told to myself maybe it's a versions issue, but I still getting the same problems.
5. I searched a lot here on StackOverflow & GitHub & internet in general about this issue but I found nothing.

In addition, the problem is that all these PCs worked well only for the first days after a format, but after 1 week of work its states become more and more slowly comparing to the first executions.

To be honest I was very hesitated to post this question, but I took a lot of my time to search about this topic without finding any response or any encountered issue like mine.

Comment: https://github.com/TypeStrong/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/issues/236 ?

Comment: thank you for your try, but i checked all comments, and I tried all suggestions, but i still in the same issue.